# How to correctly set nonce?

Tags: transactions, nonce

on an account with no transaction set yet,
using getTransactionCount will return 0.
Should I specify the first transaction with nonce 0 or 1?

and on the next transactions after the above is mined, calling getTransaction() will return 1, if Should i set the next transaction with nonce 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

Soldity indexes from 0 onwards;
So to find the first transaction getTransaction(0). The next transaction will be 1